# Xamarin Forms CollectionView not showing on iPhone but on Android and Android simulator

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview

I have a problem and a question regarding Xamarin.Forms and CollectionView. I implemented a CollectionView as a Main Menu and on Android it is working fine.
But on my iPhone it is not showing the CollectionView.
The ScrollView is showing I think because the LightBlue background is visible on my iPhone.

It is build for iOS 9 and Android 9.0 and with XCode 12.2.

Are there known issues with ObservableCollections, CollectionViews, some attributes or maybe someone can tell my what I did wrong.

[ViewModel, View and COdebehind for download](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/vvfs422u8srtq3d/AABXRg43L-GmBqcuYsykHzW3a?dl=0)

This is how it looks on Android:

[Android CollectionView Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtuCX.png)

This is my xaml code and C# code:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
          x:Class="FlyThePilotHelper.MainPage"
          xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FlyThePilotHelper.ViewModels">

 <ContentPage.BindingContext>
     <local:MainPageViewModel/>
 </ContentPage.BindingContext>

 <ScrollView BackgroundColor="LightBlue">

     <CollectionView Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding AllMenuItems}"
                     SelectionMode="Single"
                     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMenuItem}"
                     SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding SelectedMenuItemChangedCommand}">
                
             <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                 <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="2" />
             </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                
             <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                     <StackLayout Padding="10,10">
                     <Frame CornerRadius="50">
                         <Label x:Name="label1" Text="{Binding .}" FontSize="Title" WidthRequest="100"
                                VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference label1}}"/>
                          </Frame>
                     </StackLayout>
                 </DataTemplate>
             </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
         </CollectionView>
 </ScrollView>
```

```
AllMenuItems = new ObservableCollection<string>
         {
             "Unit Conversions",
             "Procedures",
             "Wind Calculations",
             "Fuel Calculations"
         };
  

        
     string selectedMenuItem;
     public string SelectedMenuItem
     {
         get => selectedMenuItem;
         set
         {
             selectedMenuItem = value;

             var args = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedMenuItem));

             PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, args);
         }
     }
```

```html
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/86F2FBA6-F8C2-45C4-B69F-16B8C3E86F32/FlyThePilotHelper.iOS.app/Xamarin.iOS.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/86F2FBA6-F8C2-45C4-B69F-16B8C3E86F32/FlyThePilotHelper.iOS.app/System.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/86F2FBA6-F8C2-45C4-B69F-16B8C3E86F32/FlyThePilotHelper.iOS.app/Mono.Security.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/86F2FBA6-F8C2-45C4-B69F-16B8C3E86F32/FlyThePilotHelper.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS.exe [External]
Thread started:  #2
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/86F2FBA6-F8C2-45C4-B69F-16B8C3E86F32/FlyThePilotHelper.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS.Library.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/86F2FBA6-F8C2-45C4-B69F-16B8C3E86F32/FlyThePilotHelper.iOS.app/netstandard.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/86F2FBA6-F8C2-45C4-B69F-16B8C3E86F32/FlyThePilotHelper.iOS.app/System.Core.dll [External]
2020-11-30 14:30:02.787 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[7668:1665004] Content folder: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9469DEB2-DFD5-46D4-9F3C-4BD127791084/Documents/FlyThePilotHelper.iOS.content

Thread started:  #3
2020-11-30 14:30:02.806 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[7668:1665004] Forms app path /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9469DEB2-DFD5-46D4-9F3C-4BD127791084/Documents/FlyThePilotHelper.iOS.content/FlyThePilotHelper.iOS.exe

2020-11-30 14:30:02.808 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[7668:1665004] warning: Symbol file /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9469DEB2-DFD5-46D4-9F3C-4BD127791084/Documents/FlyThePilotHelper.iOS.content/FlyThePilotHelper.iOS.exe.mdb doesn't match image /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9469DEB2-DFD5-46D4-9F3C-4BD127791084/Documents/FlyThePilotHelper.iOS.content/FlyThePilotHelper.iOS.exe

Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9469DEB2-DFD5-46D4-9F3C-4BD127791084/Documents/FlyThePilotHelper.iOS.content/FlyThePilotHelper.iOS.exe
Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9469DEB2-DFD5-46D4-9F3C-4BD127791084/Documents/FlyThePilotHelper.iOS.content/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.dll [External]
2020-11-30 14:30:02.831 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[7668:1665004] Xamarin.Forms AppDelegate name: AppDelegate


=================================================================
    Native Crash Reporting
=================================================================
Got a segv while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

=================================================================
    Native stacktrace:
=================================================================

    0x100b50120 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/86F2FBA6-F8C2-45C4-B69F-16B8C3E86F32/FlyThePilotHelper.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_dump_native_crash_info
    0x100b46cbc - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/86F2FBA6-F8C2-45C4-B69F-16B8C3E86F32/FlyThePilotHelper.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_handle_native_crash

    0x100cfca48 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/86F2FBA6-F8C2-45C4-B69F-16B8C3E86F32/FlyThePilotHelper.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : do_icall
    0x100cfb0e8 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/86F2FBA6-F8C2-45C4-B69F-16B8C3E86F32/FlyThePilotHelper.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : do_icall_wrapper

    0x100b53a60 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/86F2FBA6-F8C2-45C4-B69F-16B8C3E86F32/FlyThePilotHelper.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_sigsegv_signal_handler_debug
    0x1d60fa290 - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib : <redacted>
    0x18c92da78 - /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib : <redacted>
    0x18c91e84c - /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib : <redacted>
    0x18c92d8a4 - /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib : <redacted>
    0x18c91f18c - /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib : <redacted>
    0x18c92e344 - /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib : <redacted>
    0x18c92de2c - /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib : <redacted>
    0x18c92fd14 - /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib : <redacted>
    0x18c921d44 - /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib : <redacted>

    0x100cf1b64 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/86F2FBA6-F8C2-45C4-B69F-16B8C3E86F32/FlyThePilotHelper.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : interp_exec_method_full
    0x100ceff88 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/86F2FBA6-F8C2-45C4-B69F-16B8C3E86F32/FlyThePilotHelper.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : interp_runtime_invoke

    0x100b3b8f4 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/86F2FBA6-F8C2-45C4-B69F-16B8C3E86F32/FlyThePilotHelper.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_jit_exec
    0x100ceda5c - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/86F2FBA6-F8C2-45C4-B69F-16B8C3E86F32/FlyThePilotHelper.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : xamarin_main

    0x100b02ea8 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/86F2FBA6-F8C2-45C4-B69F-16B8C3E86F32/FlyThePilotHelper.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : main
    0x18c91d6c0 - /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib : <redacted>

=================================================================
    Basic Fault Address Reporting
=================================================================
Memory around native instruction pointer (0x10a42f11c):0x10a42f10c  
    0x100b56d3c - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/86F2FBA6-F8C2-45C4-B69F-16B8C3E86F32/FlyThePilotHelper.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_jit_runtime_invoke
    0x100c05260 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/86F2FBA6-F8C2-45C4-B69F-16B8C3E86F32/FlyThePilotHelper.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_runtime_invoke_checked
    0x100c0a504 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/86F2FBA6-F8C2-45C4-B69F-16B8C3E86F32/FlyThePilotHelper.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_runtime_exec_main_checked

b0 21 38 2f 91 e0 03 13 aa  s.+.a...!8/.....
0x10a42f13c  02 00 ae 52 63 bc 00 94 60 82 01 91 ce bc 00 94  ...Rc...`.......

=================================================================
    Managed Stacktrace:
=================================================================
      at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
      at ObjCRuntime.Dlfcn:_dlopen <0x00026>
      at ObjCRuntime.Dlfcn:dlopen <0x00010>
      at Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS.Applications:LoadFrameworks <0x0009e>
      at Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS.Applications:Main <0x00202>
      at <Module>:runtime_invoke_direct_void_string[] <0x00092>
=================================================================

c3 bc 00 94 e0 03 13 aa 5f 00 03 94 20 00 20 d4  ........_... . .
0x10a42f11c  f4 4f be a9 fd 7b 01 a9 fd 43 00 91 73 09 00 b0  .O...{...C..s...
0x10a42f12c  73 82 2b 91 61 08 00 
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #4
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #5
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #6
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #7
Die App wurde beendet.
```

Comment: Any errors or messages showing in the application output/console? Also, try removing the ScrollView. The CollectionView already scrolls vertically, and having two controls that scroll the same direction will cause problems.

Comment: Hello I tried to remove the Scrollview but nothing changed. I have no errors because I do not use an iOS simulator it was on an actual device.

Comment: you can interactively debug with an iOS device

Comment: I test your codes on ios simulator,it could work,maybe you could show the complete viewmodel codes or share a simple sample.

Comment: Okay I try to interactively debug it with my device. Yes no problem I can share my ViewModel und my View. Give me a little bit of time.

Comment: Codefiles added via a DownloadLink from Dropbox.

Comment: I test with the codes file you update above,it still works.Try to delete obj and bin,rebuild the project.

Comment: Hmm ok but its fine that it works. I built it with appcenter.ms with XCode 12.2 Mono 6.12 and Xamarin iOS 14.4. For minimum iOS 9. Could you tell me whether you used other versions?

Comment: I test it on Xamarin.Forms 4.6.0.1141 and xamarin-ios-14.2 for minimum ios 8.

Comment: Okay thats weird i used the same settings to build it again but I have the same problem. Maybe it is becausew of build settings?

Comment: I got some more information. With Xamarin Hot restart I got a stacktrace.
I uploaded the txt file in the post above.

Comment: Do you try to create a new project to test it ?

Comment: Yes I added a new iOS project in the solution.

Comment: I will try to create a whole new solution.